# Reverse output of vector array giving strange result

Tags: c++

I am starting off with learning a bit more about vectors. One of the first practice exercises I was told to do was to output the contents of the array using 'iterator format'. As an additional exercise I was told to try and print the array in reverse using the same method as it similar to pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 vector<int> arr;
 arr.push_back(1);
 arr.push_back(2);
 arr.push_back(3);
 arr.push_back(4);

 for(vector<int>::iterator it = arr.end(); it >= arr.begin(); it--){
 cout << *it << endl;
 }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
-820575969
4
3
2
1
```

The program is working and it is printing out the numbers in the array in reverse order. However why is the first thing outputted some long negative number? Thanks for any help.

R,
John

Comment: You should use `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) iterator of a vector doesn't reference valid data.  The valid data is from `[begin, end)` (half closed and half open range).  So you can't expect the `*` operator on it to work.  In fact, doing so is undefined behavior.

Instead, to iterate backwards, use the [reverse_iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) `arr.rbegin()` and `arr.rend()` and use the `++` operator as so:

```
for(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator it = arr.rbegin(); it != arr.rend(); ++it)
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "*half* closed and *half* open range"?

Comment: @499602D2, I am using [this terminology](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html)